# Get position in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a small game, but I have some start up problems.

When I try to get the position of track or trackCont, it always returns x: 0, y: 0. Doesn't get right position moving the DIV with:

```
float: right;
display: block;
```

and even doesn't work using:

```
position: absolute;
left: 100px;
```

Here's the code I am using:

```
var Player = new Array();
var trackEntity;

function getPosition(elem){
    xPos = 0;
    yPos = 0;
    while(elem){
        xPos += (elem.offsetLeft + elem.clientLeft);
        yPos += (elem.offsetTop + elem.clientTop);
        elem = elem.offsetParent;
    }

    return {x: xPos, y: yPos};
}

window.onload = function(){
    trackEntity = document.getElementById("trackCont");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i += 1){
        Player[i] = new Object();
        document.body.innerHTML += "<div id='p" + i + "' class='player'></div>";
        Player[i].entity = document.getElementById("p" + i);
        Player[i].entity.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" 
                                               + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ", "
                                               + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ", "
                                               + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + 
                                                 ")";
        Player[i].entity.style.left = (getPosition(trackEntity).x) + 20;
        Player[i].entity.style.top = (getPosition(trackEntity).y) + 20;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dh8uf6Lp/

Comment: Do you mean **set**, not get? Are you trying to set the position, or get it?

Comment: Get track position and then set players position

Comment: In the jsfiddle, the image is in the expected position.

Comment: Found this problem before, can be annoying when using `div`s for games / animation. Just for next time, I'd recommend `canvas` — it's much better at rendering, built for speed and much more flexible in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to supply a `unit` to when assigning a value to css `left`.

```
 Player[i].entity.style.left = (getPosition(trackEntity).x) + 20 +"px";
```

If you assign a value to a css dimension or position property it will not update when no unit is given.

It seems that when `getPosition(trackEntity)` is called it doesn't know where it is in the DOM. This is caused by

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<div id='p" + i + "' class='player'></div>";
```

This causes the browser to redraw all elements and `trackEntity` loses it reference.

Solution: do not insert html via innerHTML, but create the div and append it to the DOM.

```
 Player[i].entity = document.createElement("div");
 Player[i].entity.id = "p" + i;
 //etc.

 document.body.appendChild(Player[i].entity);

 //Run position code.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dh8uf6Lp/3/

Comment: The player (div id=p) positioning works properly, but the getPosition() returns always 0 when called with trackEntity

Comment: It shouldn't in modern browsers. Assignment without units should be ignored.

Comment: @Insane96MCP this should do it.